# Highcharts x-axis not formatting right when showing only 1 datapoint

Tags: highcharts

The issue is that even there is space it does not print days/months/years to the label. I suppose it is supposed to automatically choose which formatting to use?

Documentation says: "For a datetime axis, the scale will automatically adjust to the appropriate unit.".

Imho it does not. Please see the example: http://jsfiddle.net/gxLc9/1/

In the demo the timestamp refers to Tue, 16 Apr 2013 21:00:00 GMT. In the chart it only shows hh/mm/ss... which is not nice when showing for example timelines of an event. The user won't have any idea when the "dot" on the chart is supposed to be if only hours, minutes etc are shown.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 25
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Test for x-axis label',
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: "datetime",
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                second: '%H:%M:%S',
                minute: '%H:%M',
                hour: '%H:%M',
                day: '%e. %b',
                week: '%e. %b',
                month: '%b \'%y',
                year: '%Y'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            type: "linear",
            title: {
                text: 'y'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: "#c0d0e0",
                    shadow: false,
                    style: {
                        padding: "11px"
                    },
                    formatter: function ()
                    {
                        var value = this.y;
                        var d = new Date(this.x);
                        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + d.toString() + ': ' + value;
                    }
                },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -10,
            y: 100,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'serie',
            type: "spline",
            data:[[1366146000000, 3]]
        }]
    });
});
```

Regards, Tim.

Answer (score 2):

Use this to show the format as you want:

```
 return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%I:%M %p', this.x);
```

In the format you can use what format you want.

Comment: In place of '%I:%M %p' you can use '%H:%M:%S'and other also.